# Laravel's CSRF token and load balancing

Tags: php, session, laravel, csrf

Consider this scenario:

An application has a login route that is protected by Laravel's CSRF filter:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function() {

    Route::post('/doLogin', array('as' => 'doLogin', 'uses' => 'MainController@doLogin'));

});
```

The application sits behind a load balancer, where each request is doled out randomly to either `server01` or `server02`. Laravel is configured to persist sessions in a database, which is shared by both `server01` and `server02`. The standard path to follow is: a user accesses `/`, enters their credentials into a login form, and submits those credentials to `/doLogin`, which checks the token, processes the credentials, and returns the user to `/` on error, or `/home` on success.

My question is this: since there's no guarantee that a user who accesses `/` on `server01` will post to `/doLogin` on `server01`, will Laravel's built-in CSRF tokens work? Or since the token is stored in `Session`, will it work regardless of which server ends up being assigned by the LB?

Comment: I use redis for sessions across multiple load balanced servers, but csrf works perfectly irrespective of which server gets hit.... and I have specifically tested it by taking servers down between requests

Answer (score 5):

CSRF will work regardless of which server it hits if session is shared between these servers.

Database, Cookie and memcached/redis session drivers are good.

File session driver should not work ususally.

CSRF token from client is compared with the one in the session.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **cookie** or **database** driver for session handling .

for more info read [laravel session doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session) .